# SQL Query excuting very slow: Need Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mysql-workbench, query-optimization

The following is executing very slow and takes ages to execute. Even with an empty result set, it takes around 280 seconds. There are a few case statements in the query. Some help to optimize the query will be highly appreciated.

**Execution Plan:**
The plan is depending upon the date variable input the field of the date range will be changed in the where clause.
eg: if the date = '1' then, the date range will be queried based on a.created_date, and if the date = '2' then, the date range will be queried based on t.active_datetime

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT  @n:=@n+1 No,  a.name customer_name, a.id_number AS customer_id, a.email AS email_address, CONCAT(a.mobile_country_code, '-', a.mobile_number) AS contact_no,
t.status AS status, a.created_date AS registration_date,  a.account_type, a.account_id AS account_no, c.wallet_id AS wallet_account_no, t.old_serial_no AS r_id,
t.active_datetime AS activation_date, v.number AS registration_no,  v.class AS lass,  (CASE WHEN t.is_free = true THEN 'Yes'  ELSE 'No'  END ) AS replacement,
a.reg_source AS channel, (CASE WHEN a.reg_source = 'ADMIN' THEN t.last_modified_by  ELSE 'SYSTEM'  END )  AS activated_by, t.replacement_date AS replacement_date, 
t.new_serial_no AS new_r_id, d.description AS reason, t.terminated_datetime AS tag_termination_date
FROM abc a 
LEFT JOIN def b ON (b.id = a.id) 
LEFT JOIN ghi c ON (c.id = b.id),  tags t
LEFT JOIN jkl v ON (v.id = t.id)
LEFT JOIN mno d ON (d.code = t.reason_code),
(SELECT @n:= 0) AS n , (SELECT @date := '3') AS date
WHERE
a.account_type IN ( 'PRIVATE') AND  a.account_status IN ( 'ACTIVE') AND t.status IN ('ACTIVE') AND
a.reg_source IN ('ADMIN') AND   
CASE 
WHEN @date = '1' THEN a.created_date BETWEEN '2020-11-24'  AND '2020-11-24'
WHEN @date = '2' THEN t.active_datetime BETWEEN '2020-11-24'  AND '2020-11-24'
WHEN @date = '3' THEN t.replacement_date BETWEEN '2020-11-24'  AND '2020-11-24'
WHEN @date = '4' THEN t.terminated_datetime BETWEEN '2020-11-24'  AND '2020-11-24'  
END ;
```

Comment: Hi - please provide the execution plan for this query

Comment: @NickW Thanks for your reply. The plan is depending upon the date variable input the field of the date range will be changed in the where clause.
 eg: if the date = '1' then, the date range will be queried based on a.created_date, and if the date = '2' then, the date range will be queried based on t.active_datetime

Comment: Ok, so is the query slow regardless of the date value or only for specific date values? If you provide the Explain Plan for the slowest value of date then we can start with that

Comment: It is always executing slow. even when there are no records that satisfy the where clause also takes a very long time. So, I am suspecting that it may be due to these case statements.

Comment: You have not given us enough information to help you very well. [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question to give us more information.

Comment: Show us the two `EXPLAINs`; the hand-waving does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding indexes to help speed up the search.

```
CREATE INDEX abc_for_big_query
          ON abc (account_type, account_status, reg_source, created_date);

CREATE INDEX tags_for_big_query_active ON tags (status, active_datetime);
CREATE INDEX tags_for_big_query_replacement ON tags (status, replacement_date );
CREATE INDEX tags_for_big_query_terminated ON tags (status, terminated_datetime );
```

These indexes will allow the query planner to use [index range scans](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html) to do the search operations. They are more efficient than full table scans.

As you optimize this query, think of it as four entirely different queries, one for each value of your `@date` variable. Why? The search criteria differ a lot.

If you need absolutely the top performance you may need to rewrite this as four different queries. But recent MySQL query planners may allow you to keep this four-way query.

### notes

- Make sure your date datatypes are DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP. If you store your dates in text strings you'll have a really hard time getting decent performance.
- You have where clauses like this:  `a.created_date BETWEEN '2020-11-24'  AND '2020-11-24'`.

  That actually means `a.created_date = '2020-11-24 00:00:00'`.  Why? Because the constant date `2020-11-24` actually expands to `2020-11-24 00:00:00`. And `val BETWEEN x and x` means `val = x`.

  If you want everything with a `created_date` anytime on `2020-11-24` use this

  ```
   WHERE a.created_date >= '2020-11-24'
     AND a.created_date <  '2020-11-24' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```

  This will still use the indexes I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
@n:=@n+1
```

The use of @variables will be outlawed in a future version.  If this is a `ROW_NUMBER`, that function may provide what you need.

You seem not to use `b`; get rid of it.

Don't use `LEFT` if rows from the 'right' table are required.

This may be the big speed killer:

```
, tags t
```

Don't mix `JOIN` and `,`.  Be sure to have an `ON` clause associated with each `JOIN`.

Construct the query rather than make it dynamic like you are doing with @date.  This may provide a significant speedup.  After that, add these indexes:

```
a: INDEX(account_type, account_status, reg_source, created_date)

t: INDEX(status, active_datetime),
t: INDEX(status, replacement_date),
t: INDEX(status, terminated_datetime)
```